# Why $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)\, x^n}{n!} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Let $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ a function that is $\mathcal C^\infty(\mathbb R) $. Suppose $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\,x^k$$
converge and its radius is $R$. Why $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\,x^k$$
for all $x\in ]-R,R[$ ?

I know that for a fixed $n$, $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\,x^k+o(x^n),$$
in a neighborhood of $0$, but a priori it won't be correct for $x$ too large (take for example the sinus or exponential, we have $$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!},$$
for all $x\in \mathbb R$, not only in a neighborhood of $O$. So why can we extend the formula to all $x\in\mathbb R$ ?

---

Ok, let forget $e^{-1/x^2}$. Consider for example $\sin(x)$.
Why $$\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n)!}x^{2n},$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R$ whereas $$\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2k}}{(2k)!}+o(x^{2n})$$
in a neighborhood of $0$ only.

Comment: I don't understand what is asked. The first question is "Why [...] for all $x\in(-R,R)$?" (this is true) The second is "why can we extend the formula to all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?" (we cannot) Which of the two is your question?

Comment: So... after your edit, your question seems to boil down to understanding what $o(\cdot)$ means.

Comment: It mean that $$|\sin(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^{2k}}{(2k)!}|\leq x^{2n}\varepsilon(x)$$ with $\varepsilon(x)\to 0$ when $x\to 0$... so ? @ClementC.

Comment: So it is *inherently* around a specific point. It cannot be "extended" over the reals, the Landau $o(\cdot)$ is by very definition a local statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false.  For example, if $f(x)=\exp(-1/x^2)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$, then $f$ is $C^\infty$ with $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k$.  In particular, $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\,x^k$$ converges for all $x$ since every term is $0$.  However, it is not true that $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\,x^k$$ for any $x$ besides $x=0$.

(It happens to be true for certain functions like $f(x)=e^x$, but you must prove it using particular properties of those functions.  How you prove it in the case $f(x)=e^x$ depends on what your definition of $e^x$ is; often $e^x$ is simply defined to be $\sum\frac{1}{k!}x^k$ so it is true by definition.)

Comment: So how would you prove it for $e^x$ ? My definition is $(e^x)'=e^x$ and $e^0=1$.

Comment: One way to prove it is to show that $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$ satisfies those two properties.  If you know that there can only be one function satisfying those properties (e.g., by the theory of ODEs), you're done.

Comment: Ok ok. And for an $\sin(x)$ ? (sorry I want a general example for more complicated function)

Comment: Again, that depends on your definition of $\sin(x)$.

Comment: My definition of $\sin$ ? It's the sinus function... the trigonometric function... take the circle of radius 1, a point $x$ on the circle, then the sinus it's the ordinate... you have 159K pts, you should know what's I'm talking about :-)

Comment: I know what it is, but there are many different definitions and how you prove things depends on what definition you start from.  Starting from the geometric definition, you can prove that $f(x)=\sin x$ is a solution to the differential equation $f''(x)=-f(x)$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$.  Then you can prove the Taylor series for sine also has these properties, so they must be equal.

Comment: ok ok, so there is no general way to prove that a series converge to a function ? (except with ODE's)

Comment: There are lots of other general methods too.  One is to use explicit formulas for the remainders (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) to estimate them and prove they converge to $0$.  Another is to show that your function extends to a complex-differentiable function on an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and then a theorem in complex analysis says it must agree with its Taylor series on the region of convergence.

Comment: The point is, since the result is not true for all functions, whatever method you use for any particular function will need to use something special about that function.  What you can use depends on what exactly you know about the function.

Comment: But for example, if I say that for $x\in (-R,R)$ we have $$ |f(x)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k|\leq \left|\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c_x)}{n!}\right|R^k\leq \frac{M}{n!}R^n\to 0,\ when\ n\to \infty $$ where $M=\sup_{[0,x]}|f^{(n+1)}|$ it's not correct since $M$ depend on $n$ and it can explose, right ? But if the $f^{(n)}$ where uniformly bounded on (which is the case for example for $\sin$), then such an argument is working, right ? Thank you :)

Comment: Right, that works if you can get a bound on $M$ which is independent of $n$.  That's one typical way you use the remainder formulas to prove it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. The function
$$
f(x)=\cases{0& if $x=0$\\e^{-1/x^2}& otherwise}
$$
is $C^{\infty}$, and for any $k\in\Bbb N$ we have $f^{(k)}(0)=0$, so the series converges for all $x$, but only converges to $f(x)$ for $x=0$.

Comment: And is there a function s.t. $f\in \mathcal C^\infty (\mathbb R)$, $f^{(n)}(0)\neq 0$ for all $n$ but $f(x)\neq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^{k}$ for some $x\in (-R,R)$ ?

Comment: @MSE Take this $f$ and add, say, $e^x$ to it. The series you get then converges to $e^x$ rather than $f(x)+e^x$.

Comment: @MSE A bit more pathological example from that Arthur gave: $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-2^{n-1}}\cos(2^nx)$$

Answer (score 0):

This is true only for what is called *analytic functions* (sums of power series).

It happens that for functions of a complex variable, being differentiable (in the complex sence) implies infinitely differentiable and even analytic, whereas for functions of a real variable, infinitely differentiable does not imply analytic. The function $\mathrm e^{-\tfrac1{x^2}}$ mentioned in other answers is an example of a $\mathcal C^\infty$ function which is not analytic.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the size of the radius.

For some $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\,x^k$ you will have $r=\lim_{k\to\infty}|\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}|$.

Calculating the radius for $e^x$ provides $r=\infty$.

But then consider the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$. Its MacLaurin series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k$ has a radius of convergence of $r=1$. But that given fraction function clearly is well-defined beyond too.

Just plot the graph of that latter function and you would understand that the series would be well-defined even for $x\in [-1,1)$.

--- rk